# Checking an boolean condition,which way is better

Tags: java

Which way is better to check a boolean value and why?
I have a code in which a method is called when the previous methods returned true.
I came up with different approaches to achive that , which one is better? please provide the reason for the answer.

```
boolean check1=methodA();

boolean check2=methodB();

boolean check3=methodC();
```

Is this way better

```
if(check1==check2==check3==true){

method4();

}
```

or this?

```
if(check1 && check2 && check3){

method4();

}
```

Comment: i would go for way 2 because its easier to read

Comment: The first method does not mean what you think it means

Comment: Your first option is confusing... false==false==true==true would go within the if condition and it is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, there are four ways to satisfy the first condition (some have been mentioned, but I'll collect them for easy overview)

In order of appearance, `check1, check2, check3`

- `false, false, true` (because `false == false` is `true`)
- `false, true, false` (because `false == true` is `false`)
- `true, false, false` (because `true == false` is `false`)
- `true, true, true` (because `true == true` is `true`)

It should come as no surprise that this is exactly the truth table of XNOR aka logical equality.

Technically this makes it correct according to "[`true`] if the previous methods have returned true as the value", it *is* true if all the checks are true, it is just also true in some other cases and "if" says nothing about that since it's an unidirectional implication. But most likely you meant *iff* (if and only if), and then it's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(check1 && check2 && check3){
    method4();
}
```

has different meaning than

```
if(check1==check2==check3==true){
    method4();
}
```

`true==false==false==true` is `true` when `true&&false&&false` is obviously `false`. Why? When we have operators with the same precedence, we go from left to right.

`check1==check2==check3==true` is in fact:

```
(((check1==check2)==check3)==true)
(((true==false)==false)==true)
((    false    ==false)==true)
(         true         ==true)
               true
```

Answer (score 1):

The first variant is wrong. It gives not the expected result for `check1 = true`, `check2 = false` and `check3 = false`